# Visual Studio Blend: using physical Windows Phone as a target device

Tags: windows-phone, blend

Okay, okay - this should be simple, but I just can't figure it out, and Google isn't helping.  I just bought a Lumia 635 for developing apps for the Windows store, and I'm using Blend to make my apps in HTML and JS.  I've been getting along just fine so far, but it seems that I'm unable to select my WP as a target device.
[image]

I've already "unlocked" my windows phone device so that I can use it to develop.  I don't believe it's to do with drivers since I would assume Win8 has the drivers inbuild.  I'm wondering, is this even possible from within blend?  There is a separate program named "Windows Phone App Deployment".  Do I have to use this?  There seems to be very little concise documentation on this, so I'm assuming it's not possible.

Comment: Have you created project of type Windows Phone App? It seems you are using project of type Windows App, in which case Local Machine makes sense. That option would not be available for Windows Phone Apps.

Comment: I can't believe it was that!  Do you have any recommendations for converting a universal app into a wp one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For universal apps, the available deploy targets are based on which project you choose as your startup project. By default the Windows App is the startup project, so it gives you deploy options like Local Machine and Simulator (Windows Tab). Change your startup project to Windows Phone App and you'll see the device option as well as different phone emulators.
[image: Set startup project]

[image: Deploy targets for phone app]